# Как из шрифта удалить ненужные символы?

Tags: html, css, шрифты, google-fonts, web-fonts

Хочу максимально оптимизировать свои сайты. Мне нужно из шрифтов вырезать символы, которые нигде не используются.
Как можно это сделать?
Форматы шрифтов там самые разные: woff, woff2, ttf, otf и т.д.

--- UPD ----

Я нашёл тот сайт, которым пользовался для этих целей:

https://transfonter.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вообще-то тебе сам генератор кода вставки шрифта предлагает указать, какие символы ты используешь. Указываешь и вставляешь получившийся код.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Caveat;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat&text=Заголвк"
>

<h1>Заголовок (и мимо шрифта)</h1>
```